# Why isn't RVO / NRVO always applied?

Tags: c++

A brief (and possibly dated and over-simplified) summary of the **return value optimization** mechanics reads like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization):

> an implementation may create a hidden object in the caller's stack frame, and pass the address of this object to the function. The function's return value is then copied into the hidden object (...) Around 1991, **Walter Bright** invented a technique to minimize copying, effectively replacing the hidden object and the named object inside the function with the object used for holding the result [1]

Since it's a topic greatly discussed on SO, I'll only link the most complete [**QA**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/4224575) I found.

My question is, **why isn't the return value optimization always applied**? More specifically (based on the definition in `[1]`) **why doesn't this replacement always happen** per function call, since function return types (hence size on stack) are always known at compile time and this seems to be a very useful feature.

Comment: As it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12953145/1413395), that an implementaition _is allowed_ to do this, doesn't necessarily mean you can actually rely on it. Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your comment is correct. I'm just trying to understand what are the technical reasons behind this being "not always implementable". From what I had read in the descriptions (I was never involved in compiler construction - obviously) it looked feasible, but by reading the answers I can see various types of reasons that prohibit its omnipresence : core languge / value semantics / program logic / exceptions ... still trying to wrap my mind around any of these

Comment: Well, some compilers may support it, others not. There's still a lot of poor c++ compiler implementations around (especially for particular more or less exotic CPU architectures in the embedded field). If the spec says some implementation behavior is optional, that might have a broader acceptance from compiler manufacturers, and letting them get just ahead to meet newer standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, when an lvalue is returned by value, there is no way to not do a copy. So, let's consider only local variables. A simple reason applying to local variables is that often it is unclear which object is to be returned. Consider code like this:

```
T f(Args... args) {
    T v1{some_init(args)};
    T v2{some_other(args)};
    bool rc = determine_result(v1, v2);
    return rc? v1: v2;
}
```

At the point the local variable `v1` and `v2` are created the compiler has no way to tell which one is going to be returned so it can be created in place.

Another reason is that copy/move construction and destruction can have deliberate side-effects. Thus, it is desirable to have ways to inhibit copy-elision. At the time copy-elision was introduced there was already a lot of C++ code around which *may* depend on certain copies to be made, i.e., only few situations were made eligible to copy elision.

Comment: I think you need `if (rc) return v1; else return v2;` for RVO to be allowed at all. Pretending you did write that, of course, if the compiler can determine what `rc` will evaluate to (for example, if `determine_result` doesn't actually look at either `v1` or `v2`, but simply always returns true, because of some compile-time configuration option), then RVO is still possible and allowed even here.

Comment: @hvd: I don't think _copy-elision_  (no, you won't get me to incorrectly call it :-) is allowed in the above case! See 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 31 which allows copy-elision for a `return` statement only when the expression is a variable name (bullet 1) or when a temporary object is returned (bullet 3).

Comment: Yes, that's right, I had already edited my comment to cover that: you can meet the RVO requirements (don't worry, I'm not asking you to call it that) by changing the code to use an `if` statement with two separate `return` statements in the two branches.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring that the implementation do this could be a de-optimization in certain circumstances, such as if the return value were thrown away. If you start adding exceptions it starts becoming difficult to prove that an implementation is correct.

Instead they take the easy way and let the implementation decide when to do the optimization, and when it would be counter-productive to do it.

Comment: Note that the compiler needs to make a copy or move when it doesn't do copy elision! Since the copy/move or the destructor (of the copied/moved object) can have side-effects it can't not just not do it! That is, copy-elision is **always** doing less work.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think you might have one too many *not*s in there.

Comment: @T.C.: you are right: I didn't account for the negation in "can't"... Assume the statement is adjusted using `s/can't/can/` (with the regular expression appropriately quoted...).